# response not defined in reactjs - fetching json data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to front end dev and especially to reactjs and I'm trying to fetch json data with this code, but I'm having this in console `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: response is not defined` Could u help please?

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const URL_API = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/saniyusuf/406b843afdfb9c6a86e25753fe2761f4/raw/523c324c7fcc36efab8224f9ebb7556c09b69a14/Film.JSON";

function App() {
  const searchMovies = async (Title) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${URL_API}&s=${Title}`);
    
    const data = await response.json();

    console.log(data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    searchMovies('Avatar');
  }, []);
  return <h1>hello</h1>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Code looks clean. Can you please include full stack trace errorr

Comment: Query param is not working with this api, `&s=${Title}` this api url is not working, without this parameter it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

we need more context but u can handle errors this way :

```
const searchMovies = async (Title) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${URL_API}&s=${Title}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```